# Accessing Individual objects from NG Bind Result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm fairly new to Angular so go easy on me.

I have a list of numbers that are popluated from a database.  These are coming through fine as list of numbers.  I would like to display these numbers in various parts of the webpage rather than in a list.  I was wondering if there is a way to access or reference individual entries of the ng repeat response.  Or is there another way I can access individual elements of the query .

This is my HTML

```
 <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
   {{x.Values}}
 </li>
```

(some html ommited due to formatting)

and This is the controller I am using to populate it

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("scripts/counts.php").then(function (response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data.records;
});
});
```

so rather than have {{x.values}}

I would like to be able to assign aungular variables to each row.

Thanks.

Comment: After the success callback, $scope.myData will have all the data that you can use on your controller. $scope.myData[0], $scope.myData[1]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the individual entries, if it's an `Object` you can simply call it's property:

`<li>{{myData.key}}</li>`

Or if it's an array:

`<li>{{myData[0]}}</li>`

Comment: This is almost what I need.  I am able to get the element of the array However it is displaying {"description":"TotalIdeas","Values":1079} on the page when i reference <li>{{myData[0]}}</li> I only want it to display 1079. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just append `.Values`. It's behaves like a Javascript object so you can treat it like one

Comment: Thank you so much!! you've saved me hours of googling !!